# how to add specific two columns and get new column as a total using pandas library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to add two-columns and trying to display their total in a new column and following as well

The total sum of sales in the month of Jan
The minimum sales amount in the month of Feb
The average (mean) sales for the month of Mar
and trying to create  a data frame called d2 that only contains rows of data in d that don't have any missing (NaN) values

I have implemented the following code

```
import pandas as pd
new_val= pd.read_csv("/Users/mayur/574_repos_2019/ml-python- 
class/assignments/data/assg-01-data.csv") 
new_val['total'] = 'total'
new_val.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
display(new_val)
d.head(5)# it's not showing top file lines of the .csv data 

# .CSV file sample data
#account name street city  state postal-code Jan  Feb   Mar   total
#0118   Kerl, 3St . Waily Texas 28752.0     10000 62000 35000 total
#0118   mkrt, 1Wst. con   Texas 22751.0     12000 88200 15000 total
```

It's giving me a total as a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Cavenfish, that `new_val['total'] = 'total'` creates a column total where value of every cell is the string total.

You should rather use `new_val['total'] = new_val['Jan']+new_val['Feb']+new_val['Mar']`

For treatment of NA values you can use a mask `new_val.isna()` which will generate boolean for all cells whether they are NA or not in your array. You can then apply any logic on top of it. For your example, the below should work:

```
new_val.isna().sum(axis=1)==4
```

Considering that you now have 4 columns in your dataframe Jan,Feb,Mar,total; it will return False in case one of the row contains NA. You can then apply this mask to new_val['total'] to assign default value in case NA is encountered in one of the columns for a row.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation but it seems confusing for me to understand.  Can you elaborate in code so that I can understand the flow? I'm a beginner as well.

Comment: I would be happy to help. Can you please let me know which step is confusing and what you want to do in your total column if one of the entry is NA in jan, feb or mar

Comment: there is "NaN" in column Street, state and, postal code in sample data and I'm trying to remove those rows in given .csv file.

Comment: use new_val.dropna(inplace=True) and then proceed with calculating new_val['total']. It should give you expected output.

Comment: and how we display the deleted rows?

Comment: you can use print(new_val[new_val.isna().any(axis=1)])

Comment: It's just giving me an empty data with head

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199132/discussion-between-devendra-swami-and-mayur-potdar).

Answer (score 4):

When you used `new_val['total'] = 'total'` you basically told Pandas that you want a Column in your DataFrame called `total` where every variable is the string `total`.

What you want to fix is the variable assignment. For this I can give you quick and dirty solution that will hopefully make a more appealing solution be clearer to you.

You can iterate through your DataFrame and add the two columns to get the variable for the third.

```py
for i,j in new_val.iterrows():
     new_val.iloc[i]['total'] = new_val.iloc[i]['Jan'] + new_val.iloc[i]['Feb'] + new_val.iloc[i]['Mar']
```

Note, that this requires column `total` to have already been defined. This also requires iterating through your entire data set, so if your data set is large this is not the best option.

Comment: The code that you gave me isn't working on my side.